# Is it possible to trade US stock from Europe ?

Tags: united-states, stocks

If answer to this question is positive, are there some repercussions that traders from Europe have to face while US ones does not ?

Do traders from Europe have less privileges ?

How it works all in all ?

I'm only talking about US market.

Comment: It's identical. You just use a US brokerage like someone in the US. But forget it - the tax complications are too much, unless you are talking millions of dollars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any large stockbroker will offer trading in US securities.

As a foreign national you will be required to register with the US tax authorities (IRS) by completing and filing a [W-8BEN](https://www.irs.gov/uac/form-w-8ben-certificate-of-foreign-status-of-beneficial-owner-for-united-states-tax-withholding) form and pay US withholding taxes on any dividend income you receive.  US dividends are paid net of withholding taxes, so you do not need to file a US tax return.  Capital gains are not subject to US taxes.  Also, each year you are holding US securities, you will receive a form from the IRS which you are required to complete and return.

You will also be required to complete and file forms for each of the exchanges you wish to received market price data from.

Trading will be restricted to US trading hours, which I believe is 6 hours ahead of Denmark for the New York markets.  You will simply submit an order to the desired market using your broker's online trading software or your broker's telephone dealing service.

You can expect to pay significantly higher commissions for trading US securities when compared to domestic securities.

You will also face potentially large foreign exchange fees when exchaning your funds from EUR to USD.

All in all, you will probably be better off using your local market to trade US index or sector ETFs.

Comment: Really nicely explained. I also found a link with a very proper official rules for EU-US trading relationships so I'll posted here in case someone will read this post later on. It might always help. Also thanks to the other guy who answered.

Comment: http://ec.europa.eu/trade/policy/countries-and-regions/countries/united-states/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and even common but it depends on your bank or broker. One of the main differences is that you might assume FX risk if your account is in EUR and you trade stock denominated in USD. You might also encounter lower liquidity or price differences if you don't trade on the primary exchange where stocks are listed, i.e. NYSE, Nasdaq...